# how to implement autosuggest feature in magento search functionality

Tags: autocomplete, magento

Anyone of you implemented autocomplete functionality in magento 1.3.2 for search. or is there any free extension which will be useful for me. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Isn't autosuggest a stadnard feature? I am managing a magento 1.3.2.3 site and autosuggest is there with no extensions installed.